# Bash script to convert music from one directory into another

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I've modified this script from the arch forums: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Convert_Flac_to_Mp3#With_FFmpeg

I'm trying to find specific file types in a directory structure, convert them to another music file type, and place them in a "converted" directory that maintains the same directory structure.

I'm stuck at stripping the string `$b` of its file name.

`$b` holds the string `./converted/alt-j/2012\ an\ awesome\ wave/01\ Intro.flac`

Is there a way I can remove the file name from the string? I don't think ffmpeg can create/force parent directories of output files.

```
#!/bin/bash
# file convert script
find -type f -name "*.flac" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' a; do
    b=${a/.\//.\/converted/}
    < /dev/null ffmpeg -i "$a" "${b[@]/%flac/ogg}"
    #echo "${b[@]/%flac/ogg}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm stuck at stripping the string `$b` of its file name.

Let us start with `b`:

```
$ b=./converted/alt-j/2012\ an\ awesome\ wave/01\ Intro.flac
```

To remove the file name, leaving the path:

```
$ c=${b%/*}
```

To verify the result:

```
$ echo "$c"
./converted/alt-j/2012 an awesome wave
```

To make sure that directory `c` exists, do:

```
$ mkdir -p "$c"
```

Or, all in one step:

```
$ mkdir -p "${b%/*}"
```

#### How it works

We are using the shell's suffix removal feature.  In the form `${parameter%word}`, the shell finds the shortest match of `word` against the end of `parameter` and removes it.  (Note that `word` is a shell glob, not a regex.)  In out case, `word` is `/*` which matches a slash followed by any characters.  Because this removes the shortest such match, this removes only the filename part from the parameter.

#### Suffix Removal Detailed Documentation

From `man bash`:

> ${parameter%word}
>  ${parameter%%word}
>       **Remove matching suffix pattern.**  The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern
>   matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value  of
>                 parameter  with the shortest matching pattern (the `%'' case) or the longest matching pattern (the`%%'' case) deleted.
>                 If parameter is @ or *, the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the  expansion
>                 is  the  resultant  list.   If  parameter  is an array variable subscripted with @ or *, the pattern removal operation is
>                 applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.